# Batch processing (offset of font marker) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, font

I have a group of layers with type linestring. Every line consists of simple line and marker line (font marker). I have a batch file(csv) with offsets of font markers.

Do you know if there is any function which makes this batch processing (offset of font markers) so I don't have to do it manually? Or it has to be done manually for every line separately? I have QGIS 2.6.1.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using python, find the symbol layer (type: QgsFontMarkerSymbolLayer) you can use:

`symbol.setOffset(QPointF(#offsetX,#offsetY))`

Find more in [qgis docs](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Marker/QgsMarkerSymbolLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsMarkerSymbolLayer.setOffset)